# Compare 2 metrics in Prometheus

Tags: compare, monitoring, metrics, prometheus

I'm new in prometheus, need help.

I have custom metric on my 2 servers (just shows version of application):

```
app_version{plant="dev",env="demo"} 55.119
app_version{plant="dev",env="live"} 55.211
```

I want to compare this metrics and send ALERT if they are not equal trying for smth like this:

```
alert: Compare
expr: app_version{env="demo"} != app_version{env="live"}
for: 5s
labels:
  severity: page
annotations:
  summary: Compare
```

and this alert is green.
What the right way to compare 2 metrics?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different value for the `env` label means that there's nothing to match on each side of the expression, so it returns nothing and there's no alerts. You can adjust this behaviour using `ignoring`:

```
app_version{env="demo"} != ignoring (env) app_version{env="live"}
```

Comment: If we need to ignore a few labels we should use comma (ignoring (label1,label2)) or few ignoring operators?

Comment: added pictures from Prometheus GUI

Comment: app_version{env="demo"} != ignoring(env, instance) app_version{env="live"}
also doesn't work

Comment: I figured it out. Just forgot about other labels with different values(like "service"). 
final expression like this:
    expr: app_version{env="demo"}
      != ignoring(env, instance, service) app_version{env="live"}

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus performs the `app_version{env="demo"} != app_version{env="live"}` query in the following way:

1. It selects time series matching the `app_version{env="demo"}`. All these time series have the name `app_version` and the label `env="demo"` according to [time series selector rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors).
2. It selects time series matching the `app_version{env="live"}`. All these time series have the name `app_version` and the label `env="live"`.
3. It searches for time series pairs on the left and the right side of `!=` operator with identical sets of labels according to [these rules](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators).
4. It compares the found time series pairs with `!=` operator.

Unfortunately there are no time series pairs with identical sets of labels for the query  `app_version{env="demo"} != app_version{env="live"}`, since all the time series on the left side have `env="demo"` label, while all the time series on the right side have `env="live"` label. This can be fixed by instructing Prometheus to ignore `env` label when finding the matching time series according [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching). There are the following options:

1. To enumerate labels, which must be ignored when searching for time series pairs with identical labelsets, via `ignoring()` modifier:

```
app_version{env="demo"} != ignoring(env) app_version{env="live"}
```

It is likely this query will return an empty result too, since `app_version` time series may differ by other labels such as `instance` (see [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/) about `instance` label). While it is possible to add the `instance` label into `ignoring()` list, the next option may work better.

2. To enumerate labels, which must be taken into account when searching for time series pairs with identical labelsets, via `on()` modifier. For example, the following query would take into account only `job` label when finding time series pairs with identical labelsets:

```
app_version{env="demo"} != on(job) app_version{env="live"}
```

This query may result in `multiple matches for labels` or `many-to-many matching not allowed` errors if multiple time series on one side of `!=` operator have the same set of labels from `on()` list. For example, if Prometheus scrapes app metrics from multiple targets, then `app_version{env="live"}` may match multiple time series, which are scraped from different targets:

```
app_version{env="live",job="my-app",instance="host1"}
app_version{env="live",job="my-app",instance="host2"}
```

In this case [aggregate functions](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#aggregate-functions) may be used for converting multiple time series into a single time series or into a group of time series. For example, the following query compares the maximum version at `env="demo"` to the minimum version at `env="live"` per every time series group with identical `job` labels:

```
max(app_version{env="demo"}) by (job)
  !=
min(app_version{env="live"}) by (job)
```

Another option is to use `group_left()` or `group_right()` modifiers, which instruct to match multiple time series on one side of the operator such as `!=` to a single time series on the other side of the operator. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for details. Note that `many-to-many` time series matching isn't supported by Prometheus.

P.S. The unneeded labels can be also removed with [label_del](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#label_del) function if [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) is used. For example:

```
label_del(app_version{env="demo"}, "env") != label_del(app_version{env="live"}, "env")
```